# QGIS sum fields of polygons that are contained within larger polygon

Tags: mapping, field, polygon, layer, qgis

I have two layers which are perfectly nested. There are hundreds of SA1_2016 polygons (thin grey outline - see image attached) within each State_District polygon (thick black outline - see image attached). The SA1_2016 layer has data fields contained within it. I would like to sum up the fields for each SA1 within the State_District polygon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If SA1 polygons have a field with the district ID they belongs : use aggregate function https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate with 'sum' option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have two layers, one "inside" (SA1_2016) the other "outside" (State_Districts), both have an "id" and "area" fields, use the following in Field Calculator, from the outside layer, to update its area field with the sum of respective inside polygons.

```
aggregate(layer:='inside',
   aggregate:='sum',
   expression:="area",
   filter:="id"=attribute(@parent,'id'))
```